# How to create a form that make user is_active = False?

Tags: python, django

In my Django project, there are several types of users. User types are `lead`, `manager`, `analyst`. The Leads should change every user's `is_active` attribute. I created a form and view for that. I have a users page and every user is listing here with a `for` loop.

What I want is `lead` can block a user with `is_active = False` method. But my form is does not work because I think I cannot reach the user. How can I solve it?

**views.py**

```
@user_passes_test(is_lead)
```

def users(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = makeInactive(request.POST, user=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        profile = data.get("profile")
        profile.isUserActive = data.get("isUserActive")
        profile.save()
        # get User
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=profile.user_id)
        user.is_active = data.get("isUserActive")
        user.save()
else:
    form = makeInactive(user=request.user)

context = {
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'user_list.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class makeInactive(forms.ModelForm):
isUserActive = forms.BooleanField(label='',
                                  widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
                                      attrs={'onclick': 'this.form.submit();'}),
                                  required=False)

profile = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                                queryset=UserProfile.objects.none(),
                                empty_label="Select an user"
                                )

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('isUserActive',)

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(makeInactive, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=user.username)

    self.fields['profile'].queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(
        company=userP[0].company
    ).order_by('-first_name')
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True, null= True, default='profile.png')
    isUserActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.8.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'register',
 'customer',
 'financial_analysis',
 'ocr',
 'core',
 'approvals',
 'crispy_forms',
 'ckeditor',
 'rest_framework',
 'requests',
 'ckeditor_uploader',
 'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\register\views.py", line 101, in users
    form = makeInactive(request.POST, user=request.user)

Exception Type: TypeError at /users
Exception Value: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'user'
```

Comment: Share also your Company model.

Comment: Also `default=uuid.uuid4()` change it to `default=uuid.uuid4`. [Note that a callable (with the parentheses omitted) is passed to default, not an instance of UUID](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`forms.ModelChoiceField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)([Dango Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)) in the `MakeInactive` form. Also instead `forms.ModelForm` use `forms.Form`.

Then the `UserProfile` with rank **lead** can select a `UserProfile` with rank **manager** or **analyst** and set it inactive.

You can add the current user to `MakeInactive` form and filter the `UserProfile` in the `__init__` method.

You cat try to use the below code:

**forms.py**:

```
class MakeInactive(forms.Form):
    isUserActive = forms.BooleanField(
        label='',
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
        attrs={'onclick': 'this.form.submit();'})
    )
    profile = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=UserProfile.objects.none(),
        empty_label="Select an user")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user:
            userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=user.username)
           
            self.fields['profile'].queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(
                rank_id__in=["manager", "analyst"],
                company=userP[0].company
            ).order_by('-first_name')
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

@user_passes_test(is_lead)
def users(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = makeInactive(request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            profile = data.get("profile")
            profile.isUserActive = data.get("isUserActive")
            profile.save()
            # get User
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=profile.user_id)
            user.is_active = data.get("isUserActive")
            user.save()
    else:
        form = makeInactive(user=request.user)

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'user_list.html', context)
```

Comment: There is an error :  `TypeError at /users
__init__() got multiple values for argument 'user'`. The traceback shows this line  ` form = makeInactive(request.POST, user=request.user) ` in views

Comment: @dencelden, Please share your code that you now use. Also full traceback.

Comment: @dencelden, I updated my answer. See updated __init__ method. Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the django user Model to archive it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#other code

if form.is_valid():
    x = form.cleaned_data()
    if x['isUserActive']:
        user= Users.objects.get(id=current_user.id) # handle it as you wish
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
    form.save()

#other code
```

Comment: I apply it but know there is an error AttributeError: 'makeInactive' object has no attribute 'isUserActive'

Comment: because `form.isUserActive` is wrong. After the `is_valid()` you had to call the `cleaned_data` which gives to you the fields coming fro the form. I have update answare updated